# Parameterizing MySQL queries IN clause

Tags: zend-framework, prepared-statement, zend-db, parameterized

I am using Zend's convenience methods for DB calls fetchAll. This, as the knowledgeable ones should know is a function that allows parameterization of queries. For instance, the query could be:

```
$query = "select * from user where email = ?"
$results = $this->_db->fetchAll($query, $email);
```

And this is how a parameterization can be achieved.

My query however, is this:

```
 $query = "select * from user where email in ("noLuck@hotmail.com", "hotmailsucks@gmail.com","gmailrocks@hotmail.com");
```

How can I parameterize the above query, because those emails are user inputs so I am not going to simply have them in the raw query and trying the following failed:

```
$query = "select * from user where email in ? ";
$this->_db->fetchAll($query, $commaSeparatedEmailList);
```

where `$commaSeparatedEmailList = "(".implode("," , $emails).")";`

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately ZF is a little inconsistent about how it handles this. Some of the classes do work with array parameters, but unfortunately `fetchAll()` on the adapter class isn't one of them. There are two (slightly messy) options I'm aware of:

Switch to building the query with `Zend_Db_Select` instead (which does handle it correctly):

```
$select = $db->select();
$select->from('user')
       ->where('email IN (?)', $email);

$db->fetchAll($select);
```

or stick with `fetchAll` and use quoteInto:

```
$db->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM user WHERE ".$db->quoteInto('email IN (?)', $email));
```